# How to resolve a scope variable defined in directive controller as another directive to be used within directive template in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here's what am trying to do :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var sampleApp = angular.module('sample');
sampleApp.directive('myDirective', sampleAppDirective);

function sampleAppDirective () {
    sampleAppDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$attrs', '$element', '$compile', '$log'];

    return {
        restrict : 'EA',
        controller : sampleAppDirectiveController,
        templateUrl : 'partials/sample.html'
    };

    function sampleAppDirectiveController ($scope, $http, $attrs, $element, $compile, $log) {
             $scope.placeholderDir = 'my-other-directive';
    }
}})();
```

The template in partials/sample.html looks like this

```
<div><div {{placeholderDir}}></div></div>
```

Is it possible to resolve the template into something like this in the myDirective contrroller

```
    <div><div my-other-directive></div></div>
```

I would like to make sure that my-other-directive too resolves to it's template when rendered.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to look into the $compile service.

Basically, you need to generate the markup in your directive and compile it using the $compile service.

You could do something like this in your link function:

```
link: function($scope, $element) {
    $compile($element.contents())($scope);
}
```

Didn't test it though.

You could also just discard the templateUrl from your DDO and insert your markup in your element directly:

```
link: function($scope, $element) {
    $element.html('<div><div ' + $scope.placeholderDir + '></div></div>');
    $compile($element.contents())($scope);
}
```